# How to get information about private organization's repo through github api

Tags: git, api, curl, github-api

I have owner permission on all of org repos how can I  retrieve info about repos?

I tried

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ***"  https://api.github.com/users/MYuser/orgs?
```

returns empty response

also

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ***"  https://api.github.com/users/MYuser/orgs/Myorg/repos?
```

returns 404

and please if anybody knows how to get tags from specific org repo , share the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories)

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ***" \
   https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos?type=private
```

where `{org}` is your organization